# Validation rule on Account Contact Relationship object

Tags: validation-rule, accountcontactrelation

Can anyone please let me know how to write a validation rule on Account Contact Relationship object to hold only one primary role, contact to an Account

Comment: what is your exact requirement eloborate in details and what you have tried so far

Comment: My requirement is to have only one primary role for account contact relationship if we are tagging many contacts to a account. I am trying to write a validation rule to limit to only 1primary relationship. ISNULL(ROLES) which I am checking the role is not null, but I am confusing how to check only one primary relationship is present.

Comment: use trigger instead on validation rule because in validation rule you cannot write soql and based on the where clause using limit 1 you can check and show the error message